# Cannot use free space for swap partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, memory, swap, swap-file

I am trying to increase the swap space on a CentOs-7 VM. I was running a program that crashed on the VM complaining about running out of memory. I thought increasing the swap space might fix the issue. But I am not able to do that.

1. I created a 30GB file (RAM allocated to the VM is 32GB) by running `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=31457280`.
2. I tried declaring it as swap space by running `mkswap /swapfile`. It fails and gives me an error:

```
Setting up swapspace version 1, size=28714696 KiB 
no label, UUID=97e04e0d-a257-4cf7-8d33-849a6f426601
mkswap: unable to relabel /swapfile to unconfined u:object_r:swapfile t:s0: No space left on device
```

3. This is odd because when I run `df -h`, it shows me that I have 100GB available.
   [image]
4. I searched online and I noticed two things:

   1. When I run `pvs` it shows me that I online have 4.00m amount of memory free?
      [image]
   2. I also saw that sometimes processes that are killed leave files open. I suspect this might be the case for me since I was runnning a large simulation program when it crashed. I have restarted the VM since but I am still not able to recover the lost space. I tried some of the steps suggested on some websites but I admit that at this point I am a little lost.

Can someone help me figure out what should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: your root partition is full (20k free) - perhaps that's the actual issue - also, are you able to allocate more space to the VM from the host? That would allow you to increase the size of the VM's root partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/` partition seems to be full, you have 100G left on the `/home/` partition.  Try removing `/swapfile` and recreating it in `/home/swapfile`.

Answer (score 2):

Mohammed Arshaan!
You're trying to create a swapfile under `/` (`of=/swapfile`). As you can see in your `df` output, the file system mounted on `/` consist of 50GB, and it's full.